# How to select distinct geometries and ids with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have point geometries in a PostGIS table. I want to select only the distinct geometries from this table. If a geometrie is duplicated, it should select the first appearance in the table.

I tried to following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(wkb_geometry), ogc_fid from points;
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

What is wrong with the query?

Comment: A note: This will compare the bounding box, not the actual geometry. So, two geometries that share the exactly same bounding box will be regarded as the same, and only 1 of them will be returned. It is much safer (and faster) to use id if you have.

Comment: And if you want to be sure to get the first occurrence in the table, you have to sort on something giving the right order. I don't think that the row order is guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However only their geometry is unique. In my case it is only point features. So the bounding box should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT ON(wkb_geometry) wkb_geometry, ogc_fid from points;`

Comment: This will return geometries with distinct bounding boxes, but will consider two geometries equal if they have the same bounding box.  If you want distinct geometries, use `SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_AsBinary(wkb_geometry)) wkb_geometry, ogc_fid FROM points`.